# How to set macrocode using the listings package

Tags: listings, documentation, dtx

When writing a `dtx` file, is it possible to typeset the code samples (i.e., everything enclosed in a `macrocode` environment) using the [listings](/questions/tagged/listings) package?

For completeness, here's [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright)'s [model dtx](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/) file:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
----------------------------------------------------------------
demopkg --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

Some text about the package: probably the same as the abstract.
%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
----------------------------------------------------------------
demopkg --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

\endpreamble
\postamble

Copyright (C) 2009 by You <you@your.domain>

This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
version.  The latest version of this license is in the file:

http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
You.

This work consists of the file  demopkg.dtx
and the derived files           demopkg.ins,
                                demopkg.pdf and
                                demopkg.sty.

\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{demopkg}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
%</package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% 
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
%
%\title{^^A
%  \textsf{demopkg} --- description text\thanks{^^A
%    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
%  }^^A
%}
%\author{^^A
%  You\thanks{E-mail: you@your.domain}^^A
%}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%
%\maketitle
%
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{First public release}
%
%\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
% Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which
% might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
% \marg{arg2}. 
%
%\StopEventually{^^A
%  \PrintChanges
%  \PrintIndex
%}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%    
%\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{Some change from the previous version}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro} 
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\Finale
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment `macrocode` does a lot more than just being a verbatim environment. Replacing it by `lstlisting` is not trivial:

- The indexing of macro names is lost.
- Problematic is the last line with the end tokens (`\end{macrocode}` or `\end{lstlisting}`, because of the percent char in the first column.
- The formatting of the docstrip tags is different. Also the percent char
  at the first column is automatically gobbled by `macrocode`.

The second issue can be solved by using option `lastline` to exclude the line with the end environment tokens to exclude the line, which would otherwise be set containing a percent char. The value for `lastline` could be set automatically via a script.

The third issue can be solved by putting docstrip tags in the environment body without other code lines. Then the starting percent char can be gobbled by option `gobble`. The fonts can be set to sans serif and the angle brackets can be replaced by `\langle` and `\rangle` via the `literate` feature.

Some style definitions for the preamble of the documentation driver file:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{macrocode}{
  name=macrocode,
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  %basicstyle=\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont\small,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  columns=fullflexible,
  numbers=left,
  numberfirstline=1,
  firstnumber=auto,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
  numbersep=5pt,
}
\lstdefinestyle{docstrip}{
  style=macrocode,
  basicstyle=\sffamily\small,
  literate=<{$\langle$}1>{$\rangle$}1,
}
```

Usage in the code sections, the indentation with four spaces is no longer
necessary:

```
%    \begin{lstlisting}[style=docstrip, lastline=1, gobble=1]
%<*package>
%    \end{lstlisting}
%\begin{lstlisting}[style=macrocode, lastline=3]
\newcommand*{\hello}[1]{%
  Hello #1!%
}
%\end{lstlisting}
% Some text.
%    \begin{lstlisting}[style=macrocode, lastline=7]
\newcommand*{\lorem}{%
  Lorem
  ipsum
  dolor
  sit
  amet.%
}
%    \end{lstlisting}
%    \begin{lstlisting}[style=docstrip, lastline=1, gobble=1]
%</package>
%    \end{lstlisting}
% End.
%\Finale
```

Full example:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
----------------------------------------------------------------
demopkg --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

Some text about the package: probably the same as the abstract.
%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
----------------------------------------------------------------
demopkg --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

\endpreamble
\postamble

Copyright (C) 2009 by You <you@your.domain>

This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
version.  The latest version of this license is in the file:

http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
You.

This work consists of the file  demopkg.dtx
and the derived files           demopkg.ins,
                                demopkg.pdf and
                                demopkg.sty.

\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/demopkg}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{demopkg}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
%</package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{macrocode}{
  name=macrocode,
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  %basicstyle=\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont\small,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  columns=fullflexible,
  numbers=left,
  numberfirstline=1,
  firstnumber=auto,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
  numbersep=5pt,
}
\lstdefinestyle{docstrip}{
  style=macrocode,
  basicstyle=\sffamily\small,
  literate=<{$\langle$}1>{$\rangle$}1,
}
%\let\macrocode\relax
\lstnewenvironment{macrocodeX}[1][]{%
  \lstset{style=macrocode,#1}%
}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
%
%\title{^^A
%  \textsf{demopkg} --- description text\thanks{^^A
%    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
%  }^^A
%}
%\author{^^A
%  You\thanks{E-mail: you@your.domain}^^A
%}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%
%\maketitle
%
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{First public release}
%
%\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
% Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which
% might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
% \marg{arg2}.
%
%\StopEventually{^^A
%  \PrintChanges
%  \PrintIndex
%}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{Some change from the previous version}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably.
  Lorem
  ipsum
  dolor
  sit
  amet.%
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{lstlisting}[style=docstrip, lastline=1, gobble=1]
%<*package>
%    \end{lstlisting}
%\begin{lstlisting}[style=macrocode, lastline=3]
\newcommand*{\hello}[1]{%
  Hello #1!%
}
%\end{lstlisting}
% Some text.
%    \begin{lstlisting}[style=macrocode, lastline=7]
\newcommand*{\lorem}{%
  Lorem
  ipsum
  dolor
  sit
  amet.%
}
%    \end{lstlisting}
%    \begin{lstlisting}[style=docstrip, lastline=1, gobble=1]
%</package>
%    \end{lstlisting}
% End.
%\Finale
```

Result, which shows both the original `macrocode` and the version with `lstlisting`:

> [image: Result]

Also environment `macrocode` can be redefined:

```
% Preamble of documentation driver:
\let\macrocode\relax
\lstnewenvironment{macrocode}[1][]{%
  \lstset{style=macrocode,#1}%
}{}
```

The optional argument takes the options for `style` and `lastline`, e.g.:

```
%    \begin{macrocode}[style=docstrip, lastline=1, gobble=1]
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\begin{macrocode}[style=macrocode, lastline=3]
\newcommand*{\hello}[1]{%
  Hello #1!%
}
%\end{macrocode}
% Some text.
%    \begin{macrocode}[style=macrocode, lastline=7]
\newcommand*{\lorem}{%
  Lorem
  ipsum
  dolor
  sit
  amet.%
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}[style=docstrip, lastline=1, gobble=1]
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this would be so complicated. I only noticed two small issues that I'm not sure warrant a separate question: 1) The line numbers in the `lstlisting` environment protrude into the margin, but setting `xleftmargin` to `1.4em` seems to fix that, though if anyone knows the exact number, I am all ears; and 2) adding a frame to a `newenvironment` (but not a `newcommand` enclosed in a `macro` environment (name in margin) leads to an interrupted frame for some reason.

Comment: @ThomasH 1) The width depends on the number of digits for the maximum line number, the font and font size for the line numbers. 2) I do not get interrupted frames, if I add `frame=lrbt` to style`macrocode`. Maybe a followup question with proper MWE makes sense.